# How to verify a pact?

Tags: java, testing, rake, pact, pact-broker

I have a pact published on a pact broker, and I need now to verify it with the provider.
I started by using the pact-cli on a docker image, and using pact-provider-verifier I can connect to the provider box but verification fails because the broker request does not carry a Bearer token. I could not find a way to include token to the request using pact-provider-verifier, so I went to using Rake. I installed Rake and gem, run rake pact:verify — and I saw the possibility to pass a token towards the provider — but test fails because in the config I should — it seems — define my ‘app’ but I have no idea why app I should define.
Questions I have are:

- is there a way to pass bearer token towards the provider using pact-provider-verifier?
- if not, how do I exactly configure Rake to hit my provider?
- Is there any other way of verifying a pact using a broker?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're testing a Java app, is there a reason you're not using [Pact JVM](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/readme) and using the CLI (or Ruby) instead?

There is an example JVM provider you can use as an example [here](https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples/java/provider-springboot/).

With respect to authentication, there is a [guide](https://docs.pact.io/provider/handling_auth) on strategies you can take to handle such things. If you're using the CLI you have two options

1. Stub the CLI layer in your provider
2. Use the `--header` option to add a valid bearer token

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not use JVM directly because, to my understanding, programmatic verification bypasses the pact-broker, meaning you programmatically hit the provider and match pact with result. That is not what I want, I want the broker to hit the provider. Also, the example you posted is based on PactFlow, and not a custom broker. In this latter case, the pact-provider-verifier does not have a —header option.

Comment: No that's not how it works. In both cases contracts are fetched from the broker, the broker itself does not do any verification - it just mediates the process. The languages provide a richer way to do this than the CLI. Also the example uses PactFlow but it doesn't use any commercial features not available to the open source edition of Pact

Comment: Thank you Matthew, but where do I pass broker references with the programmatic verifier? I can't see anywhere in the examples...

Comment: There are lots of examples across languages here: https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples/